# Enable permanently CORS in OVH Object Storage (OpenStack swift)

Tags: cors, openstack, ovh

I can enable CORS in OVH Object Storage (that uses OpenStack Swift) using this command

```
curl -i -XPUT -H "X-Auth-Token: xxxxxxxxxxx" -H "X-Container-Meta-Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *" https://storage.sbg1.cloud.ovh.net/v1/AUTH_yyyyyyy/repository
```

and everything works well. But after a period of time (that is completely random) this option is reset. Do you know why and how to solve that?

Comment: I am keen to know the answer too. Have you find out?

Related docs: https://docs.openstack.org/developer/swift/cors.html

Comment: I have not used Object Storage yet, but I wish to use it with CORS.
I find same report in https://forum.ovh.com/showthread.php/105599 which was written in 2 years ago.
Could you make a post to ovh official forum https://community.ovh.com/ ?

Answer (score 3):

I discovered the answer to this issue. When you visit your OVH control panel and enter the cloud containers section, their CP resets the CORS. As long as you don't log into and visit this area, your CORS should remain as you have set it.

Comment: That's a silly issue! How can I continue using my ovh control panel then? Any suggestions?